# How to create UserControl Template in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

Our organization follows same kind of display style. Hence I want to create a `UserControl` template, that should layout and style a simple ONE COLUMN TEMPLATE (here one column means one `Label`/`Widget` pair).

When this `UserControl` is used in other display, we should be able to add any number of `Label`/`Widget` pair into it.

I have seen a lot of example over internet but all over these control are being given from `UserControl` but in my case, we need to provide controls only from other page where this `UserControl` is used.

e.g.  this(below code) is `MyPage.Xaml` and `OneColumnTemplate` is my `UserControlTemplate`. this is how is should be used

```
<template:OneColumnTemplate>
        <Rows>

            <Row>
                <Label>First Name</Label>
                <TextBox x:Name="FirstName"></TextBox>
            <Row>

            <Row>
                <Label>Middle Name</Label>
                <TextBox x:Name="MiddleName"></TextBox>
            </Row>

            </Row>
                <Label>Last Name</Label>
                <TextBox x:Name="LastName"></TextBox>
            </Row>

        </Rows>
</template:OneColumnTemplate>
```

and output should be: Three rows Cotaining First, middle and Last Names here (vertically)

```
 First Name  <TextBox>
 Middle Name <TextBox>
 Last Name   <TextBox>
```

Comment: HighCore.....Can you please elaborate and show me some code to construct my UserControl

Answer (score 0):

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1" Rows="3">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Content="Last Name"/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
    </StackPanel

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Content="First Name"/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
    </StackPanel

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Content="Middle Name"/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding MiddleName}"/>
    </StackPanel
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: when UserControl Template is used over the Client part of the display (in Xaml), other developer may put any Controls inside it, as many he/she want i.e. textbox, radio button, check box, list box...So I need to create a dynamic template in which as many controls can be placed..each with one Label....all label/Control pairs will be provided from client side Xaml page